# Waiting ANY child process exit on macOS?

Tags: bash, macos, parallel-processing, process, wait

I am wondering how to wait for any process to finish in macOS, since `wait -n` doesn't work. I have a script doing several things, and in some point it will enter a loop calling another script to the background to exploit some parallelism, but not more than X times since it wouldn't be efficient. Thus, I need to wait for any child process to finish before creating new processes.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68752256/how-can-i-wait-any-child-process-exit-on-macos) but it doesn't answer the "any" part, it just says how to wait to a specific process to finish.

I've thought of either storing all PIDs and actively checking if they're still running with `ps`, but it's very slapdash and resource consuming. I also thought about upgrading bash to a newer version (if that's ever possible in macOS without breaking how bash already works), but I would be very disappointed if there was no other way to actually wait for *any* process to finish, it's such a basic feature... Any ideas?

A basic version of my code would look like this:

```
for vid_file in $VID_FILES
do
    my_script.sh $vid_file other_args &
    ((TOTAL_PROCESSES=TOTAL_PROCESSES+1))
    if [ $TOTAL_PROCESSES -ge $MAX_PROCESS ]; then
        wait -n
        ((TOTAL_PROCESSES=TOTAL_PROCESSES-1))
    fi
done
```

My neither elegant nor performant approach to substitute the `wait -n`:

```
NUM_PROCC=$MAX_PROCESS
while [ $NUM_PROCC -ge $MAX_PROCESS ]
do
    sleep 5
    NUM_PROCC=$(ps | grep "my_script.sh"| wc -l | tr -d " \t")
    # grep command will count as one so we need to remove it
    ((NUM_PROCC=NUM_PROCC-1))
done
```

PS: This question could be closed and merged with the one I mentioned above. I've just created this new one because stackoverflow wouldn't let me comment or ask...

PS2: I do understand that my objective could be achieved by other means. If you don't have an answer for the specific question itself but rather a workaround, please let other people answer the question about "waiting any" since it would be very useful for me/everyone in the future as well. I will of course welcome and be thankful for the workaround too!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The bash version that comes with macOS is already 15 years old. Upgrade with MacPorts or Homebrew, this will not break your old bash and the other obsolete utilities. If you prefer using them, they will still be available. And if, one day or another, you also need a more recent version of `awk`, `sed`, `date`, `find`, `grep`, `make`... it will be very easy to also install it.

Comment: I can think of two ways, but it depends on what you want to achieve. Can you provide some code?

Comment: Thanks @RenaudPacalet, I guess that's always an option. I will give it a try if in some time I don't get anything elegant working^^

Fravadona I am processing all videos in a directory. The script called has two parts, one more I/O intensive and the other one more CPU intensive. You can see a very basic version of my code in the question now.

Comment: A very simple way to get things done in parallel is with **GNU Parallel** which you can install with `brew install parallel`. You can find many examples by putting `[gnu-parallel]` in SO's search box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just want to limit the number of processes that are running at the same time. Here's a rudimentary way to do it with `bash <= 4.2`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

MAX_PROCESS=2
INPUT_PATH=/somewhere

for vid_file in "$INPUT_PATH"/*
do   
    while [[ "$(jobs -pr | wc -l)" -ge "$MAX_PROCESS" ]]; do sleep 1; done
    my_script.sh "$vid_file" other_args &     
done
wait
```

---

Here's the `bash >= 4.3` version:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

MAX_PROCESS=2
INPUT_PATH=/somewhere

for vid_file in "$INPUT_PATH"/*
do   
    [[ "$(jobs -pr | wc -l)" -ge "$MAX_PROCESS" ]] && wait -n
    my_script.sh "$vid_file" other_args &     
done
wait
```

Comment: Thank you @Fravadona. I thought of a similar approach, being yours a bit more compact and skilled than mine. But still I feel like it's not really as `wait -n`. Perhaps I'm just too exigent. In any case, your solution does the job and it's within reasonable length so, thanks!!

Comment: An other solution would be to use a `trap` but the code will become complex (especially the locking mechanism). IMHO it's not worth the effort because the 1sec max delta of the current solution seems good enough.

Answer (score 2):

GNU make has parallelization capabilities and the following Makefile should work even with the very old make 3.81 that comes with macOS. Replace the 4 leading spaces before `my_script.sh` by a tab and store this in a file named `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all $(VID_FILES)
all: $(VID_FILES)

$(VID_FILES):
    my_script.sh "$@" other_args
```

And then to run 8 jobs max in parallel:

```sh
$ make -j8 VID_FILES="$VID_FILES"
```

Make can do even better: avoid redoing things that have already been done:

```
TARGETS := $(patsubst %,.%.done,$(VID_FILES))
.PHONY: all clean
all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): .%.done: %
    my_script.sh "$<" other_args
    touch "$@"

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETS)
```

With this last version an empty tag file `.foo.done` is created for each processed video `foo`. If, later, you re-run make and video `foo` did not change, it will not be re-processed. Type `make clean` to delete all tag files. Do not forget to replace the leading spaces by a tab.

Comment: I like it but is `make` available without XCode command-line tools? I don't have a clean Mac to verify it

Comment: I think so. It's the old GNU make 3.81 but, as far as I remember, it is available by default, independently from XCode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is indeed quite interesting, and I will definitely use it for further problems related to old bash issues for macOS. However, since it overcomplicates a bit my work and this example is a bit basic, I prefer @Fravadona's answer. Still, I guess yours is the most powerful and versatile, so thanks again^^

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggestion 1: Completion indicator file

Suggesting to add task completion indication file to your `my_script.sh`

Like this:

```
 echo "$0.$(date +%F_%T).done" >> my_script.sh
```

And in your deployment script test if the completion indicator file exist.

```
rm "my_script.sh.*.done"
my_script.sh "$vid_file" other_args &     
while [[ ! -e "my_script.sh.*.done" ]]; do
    sleep 5
done
```

Don't forget to clean up the completion indicator files.

##### Advantages for this approach:

1. Simple
2. Supported in all shells
3. Retain a history/audit trail on completion

##### Disadvantages for this approach:

1. Requires modification to original script `my_script.sh`
2. Requires cleanup.
3. Using loop

#### Suggestion 2: Using `wait` command with `pgrep` command

Suggesting to learn more about `wait` command [here](https://linuxhint.com/wait_command_linux/).

Suggesting to learn more about `pgrep` command [here](https://linuxize.com/post/pgrep-command-in-linux/).

```
my_script.sh "$vid_file" other_args &     
wait $(pgrep -f "my_script.sh $vid_file")
```

##### Advantages for this approach:

1. Simple
2. Readable

##### Disadvantages for this approach:

1. Multiple users using same command same time
2. `wait` command is specific to Linux `bash` maybe in other shells as well. Check your current support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also thought about a similar approach, but I personally don't like creating files and so on unless necessary (tight concurrency issues, highly parallelised/fast/critical processing, etc), but it looks like it should work so I'd say it's another valid solution as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it would look something like:

```
parallel my_script.sh {} other_args ::: $VID_FILES
```